# Pylint not working as expected

Tags: python, pylint

Am using a pylint for checking error. My python codes in a directory and that directory contain many other sub folders and files. am checking recursively all folder file ends with .py. It is working fine.

My issue is when ever i run the script in main directory, only first python file get report proper. second and forth not working at all.  pylint saying

```
    ************* Module test.py
    F:  1: No module named test.py
    ***************
Global evaluation
-----------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10)
```

Whenever i run my script in main directory only first file report is proper. pylint is not checking for none of other files. ( i have almost 50 python files in sub directories) .

Following is my code :- [ver : -Python 2.7.2+ ]

```
"""
Automated error handling using pylint
1. pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc

"""

import sys
import os 

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        os.system(">output.txt")
        for r, d, f in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
            for files in f:
                if files.endswith(".py"):
                    os.system("pylint %s >> output.txt" % files)
    else:
        os.system(">output.txt")
        for r, d, f in os.walk('.'):
            for files in f:
                if files.endswith(".py"):
                    os.system("pylint %s >> output.txt" % files)
```

how to get all (almost 50 files) file report correctly, with out existing after first file report. is this is the right way to do this? . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command are you using to kick off pylint?

Comment: am directly running os.system to run pylint

Comment: Mike can you please correct me if my pylint understanding is wrong

Comment: You might need to include the directory in the filename you're passing to pylint, it seems like your script will fail as soon as you start diving down into the subdirectories. Is the only file that works also the only .py file in the folder you're running it from?

Comment: Great Marius :) you are right.  os.path.join(r, files) now its working fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the full path to pylint on the command line, i.e.

```
for filename in f:
    if filename.endswith(".py"):                       
        os.system("pylint %s >> output.txt" % os.path.join(r, filename))
```

And you won't get a very good pylint score on this script unless you use meaningful variable names :-)